# What is android hwc skip layer?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a java software with android studio and I've seen at logcat a persistent error(because is red) showing:

This doesn't seem to affect my application and continues running but bothers me.
What does it mean and how can I prevent this error?

Thanks, 
Guillermo

```
...
09-15 14:12:32.891      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.911      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.931      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.941      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.961      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.981      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:32.991      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.011      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.021      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.041      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.051      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.071      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.081      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.101      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.111      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.131      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.141      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.161      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.171      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.191      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.201      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
09-15 14:12:33.221      112-218/? E/HWC-JZX2D﹕ hwc skip layer
...
```